# Is it correct to detect environment using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == '127.0.0.1') 
{
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
}

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php';

if(YII_ENV == 'prod')
{
    $config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
        require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
        require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'
    );
}
else
{
    $config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
       require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
       require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
       require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
       require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
   );
}
```

I am trying to use multiple environments but don't what to change all the time in files so I use if condition in my `index.php` file and its working but I don't know it is the right way or not.

Comment: Environments files are located in `app_root_directory/environments/` in proper folders. You don't have to change files manually each time, just run command from console in app root directory `php init`, where you can choose actual environment - it will copy files from `app_root_directory/environments/` to proper directories and that's all.

Comment: but if I include main and main-local both file its first take main-local and than main in both environments prod or dev.

Comment: That's why you should have environment specific configurations in `main-local.php` file, which will be replaced after `php init` command.

Comment: I am a little bit confused but thank you for your replay your comment is helpful for me.

Comment: To clarify it more, all setting like DB connection, payment providers connection (sandbox vs production) should be in `main-local.php` file, so `php init` will do the work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. And this is a potential **security issue** - `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` can be spoofed, so someone may access your remote production server using `localhost` as a host name. If you're not validating host name at webserver level, then he will see your website in debug mode. From [`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) docs:

> **Note:** Under Apache 2, you must set UseCanonicalName = On and ServerName. Otherwise, this value reflects the hostname supplied by the client, which can be spoofed. It is not safe to rely on this value in security-dependent contexts.

---

You should probably keep environment-specific settings/constants in separate file outside of version control. For example in `config/environment-local.php`. And setup it manually on every instance. 
You may also use Composer hooks to copy default content of this file - I implemented something like that in [my template](https://github.com/rob006-software/yii2-app-extended/blob/215bda9c88e0e8080a037128f497e0b1d15adf86/composer.json#L72-L80). Then require this file on the top of your `index.php` file instead of your condition:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../config/environmen-local.php';

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php';

// rest of bootstrap
```